# marklogic user app server

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Which user the MarkLogic runs under if I do a default install?

I am on linux mint ML version 6 and I am doing the labs unit 5
creating the    8030-world-leaders app

In the setupdb.txt I have changed to script to use a directory in my home
like:

```
(: application server :)
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $groupid := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")
let $server := admin:http-server-create(
  $config, 
  $groupid,
  "8030-world-leaders", 
  "/home/hugo/mls-projects/world-leaders",
  8030,
  0,
  admin:database-get-id($config, "world-leaders"))
return admin:save-configuration($server);
```

but now i get a 500 error like:
500 Internal Server Error

SVC-FILSTAT: File status error: stat64 '/home/hugo/mls-projects/world-leaders/': Permission denied
[1.0-ml]

I have chmod this dir to have a+rw but still this permission denied error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the server runs as `daemon`.

To be listable, directories must also be executable. Try:

```
chmod -R a+r /home/hugo/mls-projects/world-leaders
find /home/hugo/mls-projects/world-leaders -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+rx
```

You may also need to check the parent `/home/hugo/mls-projects` and grandparent `/home/hugo` directories. If necessary, make sure they are also `a+rx`.

See also [chmod: cannot read directory `.': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800742/chmod-cannot-read-directory-permission-denied)

Comment: Hi,Seems not to work... now i have `hugo@vaio ~/mls-projects $ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 4 hugo hugo 4096 Nov 14 20:35 world-leaders
drwxr-xr-x 2 hugo hugo 4096 Mar 17  2013 world-leaders-source
hugo@vaio ~/mls-projects $ cd world-leaders
hugo@vaio ~/mls-projects/world-leaders $ ls
css  images  index.xqy
hugo@vaio ~/mls-projects/world-leaders $ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 hugo hugo 4096 Mar 17  2013 css
drwxrwxrwx 3 hugo hugo 4096 Mar 17  2013 images
-rw-rw-rw- 1 hugo hugo 1913 Feb 22  2012 index.xqy`
but still 500 error permission denied

Comment: should i not add the user to the daemon group or something?

Comment: If you look at the file /etc/sysconfig/MarkLogic it will tell you which user MarkLogic is running as (it's usually daemon).  If you have root access, become root and then do "su - daemon".  Then, as daemon, see if you can access the directory/files that you expect MarkLogic to be able to see.

Comment: You may also need to check the parent `/home/hugo/mls-projects` and grandparent `/home/hugo` directories. If necessary, make sure they are also a+rx. The same applies to `/` and `/home` but they should already be ok.

Comment: ok, this works, so I needed to also do chmod a+rx my home dir before the daemon could access the location....