# XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in merge of forest Documents: SVC-FILWRT: No space left on device

Tags: rdf, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I've been trying to use the mlcp script to load RDF dataset, composed of 2091 nquads, representing a total of 727Mio triples. 
I've used this command so far:

```
$ mlcp.sh import -username <myusername> -password <mypwd> -host localhost -  port 8000 -input_file_path /home/to/path/ -output_override_graph http://mynamedgraph -mode local -input_file_type rdf
```

The error I got after 3205 sec is the following: "XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in merge of forest Documents: SVC-FILWRT: File write error: write '/var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Documents/00000101/TreeData': No space left on device" (details here [1]) .
However I still do have enough space in my disk (28G left).

What is strange in the command is that I don't see where to pass the dataset name.

Please, what Am I doing wrong?

TIA
[1] https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gatemezing/3dce218a98ae72d2a1b8d3219ecd1fa1/raw/76144ee9740e1ba6f79eb114b9907bbe2ac59a03/mlcp.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your merge max size is set to the default 32Gb, and you only have 28Gb then it could try to accomplish a merge and not have enough space.  Also, if you checked disk space after the merge failed, it had already cleaned up the files from the merge.

It's important to remember that a merge is handled as a single transaction, if it runs out of space mid-transaction, it will roll-back and the files created during the transaction will be deleted.

[MarkLogic recommends](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/284/0/explanation-of-the-15x-disk-space-requirement) having at enough free space to accommodate merging, typically around 50% larger than your database.

Comment: Thanks @michael-gardner ! However I was trying to change the Forest directory doing the following: (1) create a folder , (2) moving the old Forest repo and changing ownership to `daemon:daemon`. When creating a new Forest, I still get in the admin UI the error `XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in initialization of forest opForest: SVC-FILSTAT: File status error: stat64 ': Permission denied` . Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: This sounds like it is a different question.  Can you please submit this as a new question, and put more detail in how you are accomplishing each step...e.g. used command line to create directory & change permissions (and compared ls -l output from old directory and new directory); the steps taken through MarkLogic admin UI to accomplish the forest switch..etc.

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution of this new issue here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987680/marklogic-user-app-sever). I needed to add also the grand-parent of the folder a+rx.

Comment: @GhislainAT Glad you found it.  Don't forget to upvote helpful answers, and accept correct answers.