# Unable to start Redis container with persistence volume

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

When starting redis container with the following configuration:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - "/data:/data"
  deploy:
    placement:
      constraints: [node.role == manager]
  command: redis-server --appendonly yes
  networks:
    - webnet
```

I get the following error in logs:

```
chown: cannot read directory '.': Permission denied
```

- Docker host is a *Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)*
- /Data exists on host
- Tried to chmod 777 /Data
- Tried chown 999:999 /Data

Comment: Any chance this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800742/chmod-cannot-read-directory-permission-denied

Comment: @brandon-barnett, thank you, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured out that it was related to seLinux on host.

The following command allowed the container to start (but disabled seLinux):

```
su -c "setenforce 0"
```

And the following one fixed the problem for good:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /data
```

Then I was able to enable seLinux again with:

```
su -c "setenforce 1"
```

I found the solution in this post: [Permission denied on accessing host directory in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker)